# What linux editor can open a 200G file for editing within a minute or two?

Tags: software-rec, editors, large-files

I'm looking for an editor that will open the file in chunks (not try to read the whole file into memory) as I'm trying to hand-edit a 200G file.

Comment: Perhaps see the question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-can-i-edit-large-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but hexedit will open large files like that. It only has what's displayed in the buffer (and maybe a little bit more) in memory. It's made for editing raw disk files (e.g., /dev/sda) and will display in hex side by side with ASCII or EBCDIC.